# Reversing a linked list (by recursion) not working

Tags: c++, c, pointers, linked-list, heap-memory

I was trying to write a code to reverse the linked list but getting wrong output.
Is there something I am missing.

Here is the function

```
void reverselinklist( struct node **headreverse)
{
    struct node *p = *headreverse;
    if(p->next == NULL)
    {
        *headreverse = p;
        return;
    }

    reverselinklist(&(p->next));
    p->next->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;

}
```

After display function

```
Input 409765
Output 4
```

Comment: Why are you passing `headreverse` as a `**`?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: because you lost the head node after the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*headreverse = p` is meaningless. You should set `*headreverse = p->next` each time to move forward, until the last node is reached.

Anyway, I changed your code to make it work:

```
void reverselinklist(struct node **headreverse)
{
    struct node *p = *headreverse;
    if(p->next == NULL){
        return;
    }
    *headreverse = p->next;
    reverselinklist(headreverse);
    p->next->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For single list use two two pointers, to update list as you can not go back.

Here is my code. Hope it will help you to understand concept.

```
void reverselinklist(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;

    first = *head_ref; 
    rest  = first->next;

    if (rest == NULL)
       return;  

    reverselinklist(&rest);
    first->next->next  = first; 

    first->next  = NULL;         

    *head_ref = rest;             
}
```

If it could me more precise please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your headreverse is not being assigned to the new head of the list. Be sure to use 2 arguments for your function, 1) head of the initial list 2) current node(same as your headreverse)

```
if(p->next == NULL)
{
    *head = p; //instead of headreverse use head
    return;
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between `head` and `headreverse` here? Please explain.

Comment: head is the head of the initial linked list. headreverse you used in it, is actually just a node you are referring to in the list. 
Suppose your linked list is 1->2->3->4 now your program does is 1<-2<-3<-4 but your head is not changing. 
**Conclusion: All you are changing in your program is next pointer of each node.** So eigther do what I suggested or change `reverselinklist(&(p->next));` to 
`*headreverse = p->next;
 reverselinklist(headreverse);`